# CookieManager.removeExpiredCookie crashes on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-cookiemanager

The following code crashes with the included thread dump on Android 4.1.2 (on a Sprint Note II).

```
CookieManager.getInstance().removeExpiredCookie()
```

Dump:

```
12-12 13:45:35.484    1551-2908/com.example.myapp W/dalvikvm﹕ Invalid indirect reference 0x4276f3d8 in decodeIndirectRef
12-12 13:45:35.484    1551-2908/com.example.myapp E/dalvikvm﹕ VM aborting
12-12 13:45:35.484    1551-2908/com.example.myapp A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 2908 (AsyncTask #2)
12-12 13:45:35.584  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-12 13:45:35.584  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'samsung/t0ltespr/t0ltespr:4.1.2/JZO54K/L900VPAMC2:user/release-keys'
12-12 13:45:35.584  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 1551, tid: 2908, name: AsyncTask #2  >>> com.example.myapp <<<
12-12 13:45:35.584  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 deadd00d  r3 00000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 408c31a8  r5 0000020c  r6 4276f3d8  r7 40863fbd
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 4276f3d8  r9 40069a6c  sl 58904738  fp 5fbfac84
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 00004000  sp 5fbfa960  lr 40033c95  pc 4085ee50  cpsr 60000030
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0  bff0000000000000  d1  bff0000000000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d2  410ca0004114a000  d3  c2040000ffffffdf
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d4  c2059800c2039800  d5  412000000000000a
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d6  c21c0000ffffffd9  d7  4210000042100000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d16 000000c1421a1640  d17 000000c1427680c8
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d18 00000000006c9688  d19 2000000840072f00
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d20 c038000000000000  d21 3ff0000000000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d22 0000000000000000  d23 3ff0000000000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d28 0000000000000029  d29 0000000000000000
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000008
12-12 13:45:35.659  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ scr 60000011
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00045e50  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+75)
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 00049f9f  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+210)
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 0004ae3d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03  pc 00298e0d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04  pc 0028cc6d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05  pc 0028cd49  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06  pc 002934d7  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07  pc 0001deb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08  pc 0004d103  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09  pc 00027324  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10  pc 000fedd8  <unknown>
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa920  00000001
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa924  40062d10
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa928  40062d10
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa92c  40062d10
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa930  40062d10
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa934  40033c95  /system/lib/libc.so (__sflush_locked+36)
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa938  4005d774  /system/lib/libc.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa93c  40062d10
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa940  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa944  40034c65  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+32)
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa948  408c31a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa94c  0000020c
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa950  4276f3d8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa954  40863fbd  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa958  df0027ad
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa95c  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  5fbfa960  00001000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa964  6c756e28
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa968  0000296c
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa96c  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa970  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa974  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa978  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa97c  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa980  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa984  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa988  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa98c  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa990  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa994  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa998  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa99c  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  5fbfab78  4276f3d8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfab7c  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfab80  40863e21  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfab84  40863e41  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  5fbfab88  58909098
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfab8c  58904728
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfab90  00000000
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfab94  5fbfabe4
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfab98  58909098
12-12 13:45:35.664  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfab9c  5d15ee0f  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r4:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408c3188 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408c3198 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408c31a8 413c0e58 40eb4690 00800000 10000000  X.<A.F.@........
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408c31b8 04000000 00004000 00006000 00000001  .....@...`......
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408c31c8 00000101 00000002 00000001 00000000  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r6:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4276f3b8 00650077 006b0062 00740069 00000013  w.e.b.k.i.t.....
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4276f3c8 420a7f98 00000000 00000000 00000023  ...B........#...
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4276f3d8 41549c30 00000000 4276f3d8 4276f3f8  0.TA......vB..vB
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4276f3e8 4276f4f0 00000000 4276f4d8 00000023  ..vB......vB#...
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4276f3f8 415480b8 00000000 4276f418 48c14184  ..TA......vB.A.H
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r7:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40863f9c bdf0b005 46294630 f01f463a 4604fd53  ....0F)F:F..S..F
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40863fac d1f12800 bf00e7e3 0005ab70 000449f3  .(......p....I..
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40863fbc 41ffe92d 460c4607 4639a803 4615461e  -..A.F.F..9F.F.F
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40863fcc ff82f7fd 98034621 ff7af7fe 46046ac3  ....!F....z..j.F
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40863fdc d0322b07 f8c6f01f b3384680 f8d8e02d  .+2......F8.-...
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r8:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4276f3b8 00650077 006b0062 00740069 00000013  w.e.b.k.i.t.....
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4276f3c8 420a7f98 00000000 00000000 00000023  ...B........#...
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4276f3d8 41549c30 00000000 4276f3d8 4276f3f8  0.TA......vB..vB
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4276f3e8 4276f4f0 00000000 4276f4d8 00000023  ..vB......vB#...
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4276f3f8 415480b8 00000000 4276f418 48c14184  ..TA......vB.A.H
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r9:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40069a4c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40069a5c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40069a6c 87780b8c 00000000 00000000 00000000  ..x.............
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40069a7c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40069a8c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near sl:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 58904718 00000026 41414db0 00000027 00000453  &....MAA'...S...
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 58904728 59927320 58a92c80 57b81e10 40ceb000   s.Y.,.X...W...@
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 58904738 4276f3c8 00000007 5fbfada8 00000000  ..vB......._....
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 58904748 5fbfaddc 0000000f 00010008 4083bf00  ..._...........@
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 58904758 00000000 00000000 56d0b770 58a8f300  ........p..V...X
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near fp:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfac64 58904728 00000000 40836eb4 58a92c80  (G.X.....n.@.,.X
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfac74 00000001 420a7f98 00000008 00000000  .......B........
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfac84 40866107 58a92c80 59b53045 5d1594d3  .a.@.,.XE0.Y...]
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfac94 58904738 20100001 00000000 40062544  8G.X... ....D%.@
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfaca4 40069a6c 00001000 40db4728 00000000  l..@....(G.@....
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near ip:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00003fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00003ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00004000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00004010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00004020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near sp:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa940 00000000 40034c65 408c31a8 0000020c  ....eL.@.1.@....
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa950 4276f3d8 40863fbd df0027ad 00000000  ..vB.?.@.'......
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa960 00001000 6c756e28 0000296c 00000000  ....(null)......
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa970 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 5fbfa980 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around pc:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4085ee30 34bcf8d3 ecbaf7d7 461d2300 b1525d1a  ...4.....#.F.]R.
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4085ee40 18ad3301 7f00f5b3 e004d1f8 4a0a4798  .3...........G.J
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4085ee50 f7d77015 490cecb2 4a0c2006 44794c0c  .p.....I. .J.LyD
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4085ee60 447c447a eb64f7d7 f7d72000 6ca3ec0a  zD|D..d.. .....l
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4085ee70 d1eb2b00 bf00e7eb deadd00d 0005fcf8  .+..............
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around lr:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40033c74 447e4e08 68336836 f000b10b 4620fa4c  .N~D6h3h....L. F
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40033c84 ffcaf7ff 68304605 4620b110 fa50f000  .....F0h.. F..P.
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40033c94 bd704628 0002982e 4604b570 4811b928  (Fp.....p..F(..H
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40033ca4 e8bd4478 f0004070 4e0fbfcb 6836447e  xD..p@.....N~D6h
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40033cb4 b10b6833 fa2ff000 f01089a0 d1060f18  3h..../.........
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory map around fault addr deadd00d:
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ bef50000-bef71000 [stack]
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ (no map for address)
12-12 13:45:35.669  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
12-12 13:45:35.774  16476-16476/? I/DEBUG﹕ !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 1551
12-12 13:45:35.774    2383-2632/? I/BootReceiver﹕ Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
12-12 13:45:35.784    2919-2919/? I/dumpstate﹕ begin
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following code to my custom `Application` subclass:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();

  CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
}
```

According to the [documentation on `CookieManager.getInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#getInstance%28%29):

> If this method is used before the application instantiates a WebView
>   instance, CookieSyncManager.createInstance(Context) must be called
>   first.

In my case, I didn't instantiate a `WebView` instance first, so this was the cause of my crash. Too bad they couldn't throw an `Exception` instead of crashing in native code.