# Invalid indirect reference on real device but correct execution on emulator

Tags: android

I'm making a web data based App, it involves downloading some information and making a dynamic view with it, so far no problem, it does in fact executes correctly on the ADT emulator, but when I loaded it into a real device this issue comes around. The solutions posted on this issue are specific to the problem given.

The code it's to broad to post it but involves an HttpUrlConnection, an AsyncTask execution, a ListView and an Adapter for the dynamic view generation, and since I don't know where in the code it's the problem or how to localize it, here's the logcat's debug dump from the cellphone.

```
05-01 18:05:47.630: W/dalvikvm(16689): Invalid indirect reference 0x41875a88 in decodeIndirectRef
05-01 18:05:47.630: E/dalvikvm(16689): VM aborting
05-01 18:05:47.630: A/libc(16689): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 16714 (AsyncTask #1)

05-01 18:05:47.740: I/DEBUG(1216): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-01 18:05:47.740: I/DEBUG(1216): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/nevisub/nevis:4.1.2/JZO54K/S6810LUBAMC1:user/release-keys'
05-01 18:05:47.740: I/DEBUG(1216): pid: 16689, tid: 16714, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> test.webtest <<<
05-01 18:05:47.740: I/DEBUG(1216): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 deadd00d  r3 00000000
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     r4 409831a8  r5 0000020c  r6 41875a88  r7 40923e8d
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     r8 41875a88  r9 40147a6c  sl 47d7b020  fp 4e00fc94
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     ip 00004000  sp 4e00f8e0  lr 40111abd  pc 4091edf8  cpsr 60000030
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d0  74726f6261204d56  d1  666572207463656e
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d2  445245483d444975  d3  494c584653585a6c
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d4  495a415243575556  d5  525148474b5a4848
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d6  4648455a55424159  d7  2f3d68746170203b
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d16 000000000000001e  d17 000000000000001e
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 3fe5555560000000
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 3fe5555560000000
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d24 0000000000000001  d25 0000000000000007
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000036
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d28 0000000000000023  d29 0000000000000001
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 0000000000000009
05-01 18:05:48.311: I/DEBUG(1216):     scr 60000013
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216): backtrace:
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #00  pc 00045df8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+75)
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #01  pc 00049e77  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+210)
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #02  pc 0004ad15  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #03  pc 00298d4d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #04  pc 0028cb9d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #05  pc 0028cc79  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #06  pc 002934a1  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #07  pc 0001df30  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #08  pc 0004cf73  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+390)
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #09  pc 00027360  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #10  pc 0002bc38  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #11  pc 0005f6b1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #12  pc 0005f6db  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #13  pc 00054293  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #14  pc 00012bf4  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):     #15  pc 00012358  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216): stack:
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8a0  00000001  
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8a4  40140d10  
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8a8  40140d10  
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8ac  40140d10  
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8b0  40140d10  
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8b4  40111abd  /system/lib/libc.so (__sflush_locked+36)
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8b8  4013b778  /system/lib/libc.so
05-01 18:05:48.321: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8bc  40140d10  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8c0  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8c4  40112a8d  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+32)
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8c8  409831a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8cc  0000020c  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8d0  41875a88  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8d4  40923e8d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8d8  df0027ad  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8dc  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):     #00  4e00f8e0  8000002e  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8e4  6c756e28  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8e8  0000296c  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8ec  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8f0  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8f4  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8f8  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f8fc  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f900  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f904  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f908  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f90c  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f910  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f914  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f918  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00f91c  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          ........  ........
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):     #01  4e00faf8  41875a88  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00fafc  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00fb00  40923cf9  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00fb04  40923d19  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):     #02  4e00fb08  46c6ed50  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00fb0c  47d7b010  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00fb10  00000000  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00fb14  4e00fb64  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00fb18  46c6ed50  
05-01 18:05:48.331: I/DEBUG(1216):          4e00fb1c  4c27ad4f  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216): memory near r4:
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40983188 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40983198 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     409831a8 40f50008 40e616f0 00500000 04000000  ...@...@..P.....
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     409831b8 03000000 00004000 00006000 00000001  .....@...`......
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     409831c8 00000101 00000002 00000001 00000000  ................
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216): memory near r6:
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     41875a68 006e006f 0069006c 0065006e 0063002e  o.n.l.i.n.e...c.
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     41875a78 006d006f 0000002f 00000000 00000023  o.m./.......#...
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     41875a88 41005c30 00000000 41875a88 41875aa8  0\.A.....Z.A.Z.A
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     41875a98 41875ba0 00000000 41875b88 00000023  .[.A.....[.A#...
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     41875aa8 410040b8 00000000 41875ac8 48c14184  .@.A.....Z.A.A.H
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216): memory near r7:
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40923e6c bdf0b005 46294630 f01f463a 4604fcb3  ....0F)F:F.....F
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40923e7c d1f12800 bf00e7e3 0005aca0 0004487f  .(...........H..
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40923e8c 41ffe92d 460c4607 4639a803 4615461e  -..A.F.F..9F.F.F
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40923e9c ffb0f7fd 98034621 ff7ef7fe 46046ac3  ....!F....~..j.F
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40923eac d0322b07 f828f01f b3384680 f8d8e02d  .+2...(..F8.-...
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216): memory near r8:
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     41875a68 006e006f 0069006c 0065006e 0063002e  o.n.l.i.n.e...c.
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     41875a78 006d006f 0000002f 00000000 00000023  o.m./.......#...
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     41875a88 41005c30 00000000 41875a88 41875aa8  0\.A.....Z.A.Z.A
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     41875a98 41875ba0 00000000 41875b88 00000023  .[.A.....[.A#...
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     41875aa8 410040b8 00000000 41875ac8 48c14184  .@.A.....Z.A.A.H
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216): memory near r9:
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40147a4c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40147a5c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40147a6c a663eec2 00000000 00000000 00000000  ..c.............
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40147a7c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     40147a8c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216): memory near sl:
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     47d7b000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000453  ............S...
05-01 18:05:48.351: I/DEBUG(1216):     47d7b010 47f0208e 47ddae0c 46f751a0 40d10000  . .G...G.Q.F...@
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     47d7b020 41875a10 00000000 4e00fda8 00000000  .Z.A.......N....
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     47d7b030 4e00fddc 0000000b 00000000 408f70c0  ...N.........p.@
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     47d7b040 00000000 00000000 46167070 47dd7300  ........pp.F.s.G
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216): memory near fp:
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4e00fc74 408f6f34 00000000 409219af 47ddae0c  4o.@.......@...G
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4e00fc84 00000001 417f6498 48d57358 00000053  .....d.AXs.HS...
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4e00fc94 40925f77 47ddae0c 48d57354 4c275459  w_.@...GTs.HYT'L
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4e00fca4 47d7b020 21a00001 00000000 00000001   ..G...!........
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4e00fcb4 40147a6c 41875928 41875928 47d7b37c  lz.@(Y.A(Y.A|..G
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216): memory near ip:
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     00003fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     00003ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     00004000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     00004010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     00004020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216): memory near sp:
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4e00f8c0 00000000 40112a8d 409831a8 0000020c  .....*.@.1.@....
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4e00f8d0 41875a88 40923e8d df0027ad 00000000  .Z.A.>.@.'......
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4e00f8e0 8000002e 6c756e28 0000296c 00000000  ....(null)......
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4e00f8f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4e00f900 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216): code around pc:
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4091edd8 34bcf8d3 ed16f7d7 461d2300 b1525d1a  ...4.....#.F.]R.
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4091ede8 18ad3301 7f00f5b3 e004d1f8 4a0a4798  .3...........G.J
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4091edf8 f7d77015 490ced0e 4a0c2006 44794c0c  .p.....I. .J.LyD
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4091ee08 447c447a ebc0f7d7 f7d72000 6ca3ec66  zD|D..... ..f..l
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     4091ee18 d1eb2b00 bf00e7eb deadd00d 0005fd50  .+..........P...
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216): code around lr:
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     40111a9c 447e4e08 68336836 f000b10b 4620fa4c  .N~D6h3h....L. F
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     40111aac ffcaf7ff 68304605 4620b110 fa50f000  .....F0h.. F..P.
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     40111abc bd704628 00029a06 4604b570 4811b928  (Fp.....p..F(..H
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     40111acc e8bd4478 f0004070 4e0fbfcb 6836447e  xD..p@.....N~D6h
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     40111adc b10b6833 fa2ff000 f01089a0 d1060f18  3h..../.........
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216): memory map around fault addr deadd00d:
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     beaa9000-beaca000 [stack]
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     (no map for address)
05-01 18:05:48.361: I/DEBUG(1216):     ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
05-01 18:05:48.541: I/DEBUG(1216): !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 16689
```

Again, the execution is correct on the emulator. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the nature of the server you are contacting?  By what sort of name or address?  Can you independently verify, say with the device's Browser, that it is reachable from the device?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hi Chris, it's a web server, it's reachable and properly working. But as I stated in my answer, It was a problem related to a Cookie not been linked to the context of the activity. On the subject of why it crashed on the real device and not in the emulator my guess is that the amount of RAM for the emulator was 1 GB and the real device 512 MB, so probably the system call the GC and erased the cookie manager (I guess...). In that case what I don't understand either, is why the system doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pure luck I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552997/cookiemanager-removeexpiredcookie-crashes-on-android-4-1-2)

It turns out that You need to link the cookies used, to the context of the activity, however while has been solved the crash, the question why it crashes on a real device but not in the emulator remains.